# Reading from file, using Scheme

Tags: file-io, scheme

I'm trying to **read from a file using scheme**, and to put it's content into a list.

The problem is how to remove the question mark, numbers, and just keeping the words. Should I use a loop to check each time? If not the case how can I get the content of the next word from the "read "?

I tried to solve it using this code but I can't find a way to call the "read" until getting the end of file;

```
(define Project
  (lambda (fileName)
    (if (null? fileName) 
        'error
        (readNext (open fileName) '()))))

(define readNext
  (lambda (fc tmp)
    (if (null? (read fc) "#<eof>")
        tmp
        (readNext fc (cons (read fc) tmp)))))
```

Comment: AFAIK, File IO is pretty implementation-specific. Could you mention which Scheme you're using?

Comment: Does this compile?  One of the *great* things about Scheme is the ability to type-and-test.  Are you using a Scheme with an interactive environment?

Comment: @Inaimathi I'm using assez gros scheme, and I forgot to add: (define open open-input-file)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most recommended way to import text is to edit and save the file as a scheme file defining a variable:

```
(define data "the text in
mydata.scm here")
```

and then calling:

```
(load "mydata.scm")
```

Many times, not every data file can just be edited and saved as a scheme file, and while newlines are automatically escaped, double quotes cannot and this creates a problem when loading the file.

Some implementation specific techniques are:

```
;Chicken
(use utils)
(read-all "mydata.txt")

;Racket
(file->string "mydata.txt")
```

A more portable function is:

```
;works in chicken-csi and Racket
(define (readlines filename)
  (call-with-input-file filename
    (lambda (p)
      (let loop ((line (read-line p))
                 (result '()))
        (if (eof-object? line)
            (reverse result)
            (loop (read-line p) (cons line result)))))))
```

Running an executable compiled chicken-csc will give error due to read-line requiring an extra file.

The most portable way to read a file is this function:

```
;works in Chicken, Racket, SISC
;Read a file to a list of chars
(define (file->char_list path)
 (call-with-input-file path
   (lambda (input-port)
     (let loop ((x (read-char input-port)))
       (cond 
        ((eof-object? x) '())
        (#t (begin (cons x (loop (read-char input-port))))))))))
```

This function is reasonably fast and portable across implementations.  All that is needed is to convert the char_list to a string.

The simplest way is:

```
;may not work if there is limit on arguments
(apply string (file->char_list "mydata.txt"))
```

The catch is some implementations have a limit on the number of arguments that can be passed to a function. A list of 2049 chars would not work in Chicken.

Another method is:

```
;works in Chicken, Racket
(foldr (lambda (x y) (string-append (string x) y)) "" (file->char_list "mydata.txt"))
```

The problems are: First, foldr is not universally recognized (SISC), though it could be defined.  Second, this method is very slow due to appending each character.

I wrote the next two functions to slice up a list of chars into nested lists until the lowest level would not exceed a maximum argument count in Chicken.  The third function traverses the nested char list and returns a string using string string-append:

```
(define (cleave_at n a)
  (cond
   ((null? a) '())
   ((zero? n) (list '() a))
   (#t 
    ((lambda (x)
      (cons (cons (car a) (car x)) (cdr x)))
     (cleave_at (- n 1) (cdr a))))))

(define (cleave_binary_nest n a)
 (cond
  ((equal? n (length a)) (list a))
  (#t 
   ((lambda (x)
     (cond
      ((> (length (car x)) n) (map (lambda (y) (cleave_binary_nest n y)) x))
      (#t x)))
    (cleave_at (floor (/ (length a) 2)) a)))))

(define (binary_nest_char->string a)
 (cond
  ((null? a) "")
  ((char? (car a)) (apply string a))
  (#t (string-append
    (binary_nest_char->string (car a)) (binary_nest_char->string (cdr a))))))
```

The function is called like this:

```
;Works in Racket, Chicken, SISC
;faster than foldr method (3x faster interpreted Chicken) (30x faster compiled Chicken) (125x faster Racket gui)
(binary_nest_char->string (cleave_binary_nest 2048 (file->char_list "mydata.txt")))
```

To reduce to alphabetic characters and space there are two more functions:

```
(define (alphaspace? x)
 (cond
  ((and (char-ci>=? x #\a) (char-ci<=? x #\z)) #t)
  ((equal? x #\space) #t)
  (#t #f)))

(define (filter pred lis)
  ; if lis is empty
  (if (null? lis)
    ; return an empty list
    '()
    ; otherwise, if the predicate is true on the first element
    (if (pred (car lis))
      ; return the first element concatenated with the
      ; result of calling filter on the rest of lis
      (cons (car lis) (filter pred (cdr lis)))
      ; otherwise (if the predicate was false) just
      ; return the result of filtering the rest of lis
      (filter pred (cdr lis)))))

(define data (file->char_list "mydata.txt"))
(define data_alphaspace (filter alphaspace? data))
(define result (binary_nest_char->string (cleave_binary_nest 2048 data_alphaspace)))
```

This works on Racket, Chicken (interpreted and compiled), and SISC (Java).  Each of those dialects should also work on Linux, Mac (OS X), and Windows.

Comment: It would seem to me that `(list->string ...)` is **extremely** portable and a lot simpler than `(apply string ...)`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will get you started.

```
(define (file->list-of-chars file)
  (with-input-from-file file
    (lambda ()
      (let reading ((chars '()))
        (let ((char (read-char)))
          (if (eof-object? char)
              (reverse chars)
              (reading (cons char chars))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Read lines from a file using "list-ec" from SRFI-42:

```
(use srfi-42) ; Chicken
  or
(require srfi/42) ; Racket

(define (file->lines filename)
  (call-with-input-file filename
    (lambda (p)
      (list-ec (:port line p read-line) line))))
```

Parsing a line using SRFI-13 and SRFI-14:

```
(use srfi-13) (use srfi-14) ; Chicken
  or
(require srfi/13) (require srfi/14) ; Racket

(string-tokenize "hi; ho")
("hi;" "ho")

(string-tokenize "hi; ho" char-set:letter)
("hi" "ho")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough to say anything about portability like the other answer, but if you were to use Racket, it would be as simple as the following:

```
(file->lines "somefile")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update: R7RS**

Under its new-ish (2013) standard  [R7RS (PDF)](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf), Scheme now provides the function `read-string`, which standardizes and simplifies the answer to the question of this thread.  Let's demonstrate it on a simple testfile called `mydata.txt`:

```
bash$ cat mydata.txt
"Hello world!"
Is this microphone on?
Testing 1 2 3...
```

To read the whole file into a single string, you can use `read-string` on a Scheme REPL like this:

```
> (read-string 100 (open-input-file "mydata.txt"))
"\"Hello world!\"\nIs this microphone on?\nTesting 1 2 3...\n"
```

That second line is, of course, the REPL showing you the string returned by `1read-string`. Notice that the quotation marks are properly escaped, which was one of the issues addressed in Will's answer.

As an aside: the first argument to `read-string` represents the maximum number of bytes for it to read. Make sure to set it to a value that reflects the actual size of your own files, lest they get truncated.

**Portability**

I verified the above solution with the Chibi, Chicken, and Gauche implementations of Scheme. At least in theory, it should also work with every other R7RS-compliant Scheme. The website schemers.org [maintains a table](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations) of implementations that claim compliance. I can't guarantee  the accuracy of their claims, obviously.

**Also potentially interesting**

In addition to `read-string`, the R7RS sandard and its implementations also provide a `read-bytevector` function, which works the same way on binary files. You can use it to read a binary file into a byte-vector.

A final R7RS function to mention here is `read-line`, which reads a text file one at a time. Hence, if you wanted to read your file into a list of lines, like Python's `readlines` function, you can now implement a Scheme version of `readlines` like this:

```
(define (readlines file)
 (let ((infile (open-input-file file)))
   (let loop ((lines '())
              (next-line (read-line infile)))
    (if (eof-object? next-line)
        (begin (close-input-port infile) 
               (reverse lines))
        (loop (cons next-line  lines) 
              (read-line infile))))))
```

Let's test it in the REPL:

```
> (define ls (readlines "mydata.txt"))
> (car ls)
"\"Hello world!\""
> (cadr ls)
"Is this microphone on?"
> (caddr ls)
"Testing 1 2 3..."
```

I hope this update helps.

Comment: Note that R6RS also has these sorts of convenience functions. You could do `(get-string-all (open-input-file "mydata.txt"))` to get a string like your first example; there is also `get-string-n`, `get-bytevector-all`, `get-bytevector-n`, `get-line`, etc. But OP seems to want to read and filter input at the character level.